# Get Parent Task Folder ID

Tags: sharepoint-server, id

I am trying to create a workflow to get the parent floders ID when I create a new task.  I want to store the ID in a column in the current item.

Comment: SharePoint Designer workflow or a Power Automate Flow?

Answer (score 0):

Workflow cannot automatically identify whether it is a parent task or a sub task.

You could create a new column to describe the task type first, then create a workflow as following picture shows.

[image]